# Xcode 5 Deployment Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I opened up Xcode5 but my app cannot deploy onto my phone.

The organizer lists it as a deployment device, but all I see in the main toolbar is just generic "iOS Device".

It's odd because on another project does list my phone when I hit the "Play" button. Anyone seen this?

I am new to Xcode. Are you only allowed to deploy one project on your phone at a time?

Both projects are Universal.

Comment: reconnect device?  Also make sure it shows the green dot next to the device in the organizer.

Comment: Did that and there is a green dot.

Comment: when you click on iOS Device, what shows in the drop down?

Comment: @nycynik it just lists "iOS" device then below all the simulators.

Comment: Is it possible your building for an OS that the device does not have?  Did you target ios7 and your device is 6 for instance?

Comment: @nycynik thanks, that was a huge oversite. I had it listed as 7.1 but still just have 7 on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the device has an older version of the OS on it.  If you are targetting a newer version of the OS it will not show.

There is no limitation to the number of apps that can be on the device, you can have multiple.  It could be that the device is not registered with apple?  Showing in the list, does it have a green dot?

here is a question with the answer: [Provisioning New Device for Development Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883914/provisioning-new-device-for-development-xcode)

Also, is it possible it is just not selected, here is a screen shot and link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Apps_on_iOS_7_Devices_with_Xcode_5

[image]

Comment: The dropdown shows just "iOS Device" and the simulators. The device is registered and was listed when I loaded another project. Not sure why it wont show as an option on this project.

Comment: You might have an update of Xcode?  You might need it to get the most recent version of the os, to match the device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete all the contents.
This should now allow your device to be seen in the devices for selection.

This has been tested and works as I had the exact problem.