# Firebase App Distribution's developer profile

Tags: ios, firebase, profile, firebase-app-distribution

After uninstalling Firebase App Distribution's developer profile from Settings->General->Profiles, I cannot find a way to get it back.
As result - I'm can't install my app's test builds.

Fabric was checking available profile every time you opened Beta.app, Firebase App Distribution - not.

Spent 2hrs in tryings :(

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you go to appdistribution.firebase.dev and try log out and log in again, it should bring you back to the flow.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely to be related to the iOS device not being registered under devices list in the respective Apple Developer account. You can visit [developer > apple > account > resources > devices > list](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list). There, you'll be prompted with the list of authorised devices to test this app. If the device is not in this list, then you can't test it and the message `Waiting for developer` will persist in the `appdistribuition.firebase.dev`.

Solution:
The user specified as `Contact Email` for the Firebase project

[image]

will receive an email from Firebase `firebase-noreply@google.com` with the subject `[Firebase] New device registered for com.example.ai` asking you to add the new device. The email should be similar to the following screenshot.
[image]

Click Add device and follow the instructions.

In case you get an `Access Unavailable`, contact the Account Holder or Admin to give you permissions including `Developer Resources` under `Users and Access` in order to add new devices. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935087/cant-access-certificates-identifiers-profiles-within-developer-apple-com) and credit to [pandurang-yachwad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167684/pandurang-yachwad)

In the next step, in case you get prompted to reset your device list, you'll have to click `reset` but this will not reset your device list.
Credit to [Fattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/fattie) who commented the below in this question [Provisioning New Device for Development Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883914/provisioning-new-device-for-development-xcode)

> To be clear, it is totally safe to touch the mysteriously-named "Reset your device list before adding any new devices." button. It does NOT ERASE ANYTHING .. on the NEXT SCREEN you get the option to get rid of devices/colleagues/etc you no longer need. It is always safe to touch that button, you won't lose anything!